# Problems with ActionBar and FragmentTransaction

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, fragmenttransaction

I am working on my Android App in Android Studio and I have encountered some problems with making Bar Tabs. I use this tutorial: [click! - youtube](https://youtu.be/IAa__qe0MLo?t=11m31s) Thus far everything is fine, I mean swiping.

Here are my imports, extension, class name ect.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ProductOrganiser extends AppCompatActivity {
```

---

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar().TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabOnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReslected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }
        };
```

Here I have some problems. First things first, `new ActionBar().` shows message: "'ActionBar' is abstract; cannot be instantiated" and what is more `FragmentTransaction` shows message: "Expression expected", `@Override` - "Adnotations are not allowed here".

[This should explain everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXAPa.png)

I would appreciate it if you provided me with a full explanation of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new ActionBar().TabListener()
```

to

```
new ActionBar.TabListener()
```

Also, `ActionBar.TabListener` is deprecated. Consider using an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for help, but now this shows me something like this: http://i.imgur.com/ZqUyOth.png?1

Comment: Change your function name to `onTabReselected`, currently it is mis-spelled as `onTabReslected`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You want to a access the interface **ActionBar.TabListener**, so instead of `new ActionBar().TabListener()` change to `new ActionBar.TabListener()`.

Secondly, you have typing mistakes, change `onTabOnselected` to `onTabUnselected` and change `onTabReslected` to `onTabReselected`. You need to override the interface methods, so you cannot give it different names.

In conclusion, try this:

```
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };
```